# How to get selected value in dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dropdownlist and I want to get the selected value to use it in my Create ActionResult but the problem is the value is always passed as an empty string and I don't know why.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidText" name="hidText" />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Armoire, "Armoire", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"  })

    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("id", ViewBag.LocalGabarit as SelectList, "Sélectionnez Armoire", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Armoire, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: Produits/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.idPole = new SelectList(db.Pole, "id", "designation");

    var armoire = db.Local_Gabarit.Select(x => x.Armoire).Distinct();
    ViewBag.LocalGabarit = new SelectList(armoire);
    //ViewBag.LocalGabarit = new SelectList(db.Local_Gabarit, "id", "Armoire");

    return View();
}

// POST: Produits/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Produits produits)
{
    localrepository=new LocalRepository(db);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string armoir = Request.Form["hidText"].ToString();
        db.Produits.Add(produits);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var reference = produits.Reference;
        var designation = produits.DesignationProduit;
        var insertproduit = localrepository.InsertLocal(armoir, reference, designation);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.idPole = new SelectList(db.Pole, "id", "designation", produits.idPole);

    var armoire = db.Local_Gabarit.Select(x => x.Armoire).Distinct();
    ViewBag.LocalGabarit = new SelectList(armoire);

    return View(produits);
}
```

Comment: Your creating a `<select>` that is bound to property `id` - does your model contain a property with that name? (but best guess is that you want to bind to property `Armoire` since that is the label and validation message you have shown)

Comment: You bound the list to `id` , where is your Model with the `id` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Hmtl.DropDownList using only ViewBag for selected value**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330059/hmtl-dropdownlist-using-only-viewbag-for-selected-value)

Comment: My model contains the proprety id :/

Comment: And even when I change it to Armoire it still the same problem

Comment: Then when you submit, the value of your model property `id` will be the value of the selected option (assuming its `string`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of

```
DropDownListFor(model=>model.WhatEverId..)
```

or make your controller receive a parameter of FormCollection And Access It With Your DropDown Name